# Can two QStandardItem objects handle different attributes from the same object?

Tags: qt, qstandarditemmodel, qstandarditem

I'm a newbie with the Model/View programming of Qt and have read the [Editable Tree Model Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html) in the Qt documentation. The nice feature in this example is that a single object (`TreeItem`) encapsulates two pieces of information that later are displayed in a single row containing two columns (`name` and `description`) thanks to overriding of `QModelIndex QAbstractItemModel::index` and `QVariant QAbstractItemModel::data`.

Now, I also have a custom class (e.g. `Foo`) containing two pieces of information (`Foo::m_name` and `Foo::m_description`) that I want to display in a single row containing two columns, but instead of subclassing `QAbstractItemModel` I want to subclass `QStandardItemModel` because it has some much functionality. However, it seems I must create two `QStandardItem` objects for each of my `Foo` objects, one to handle `m_name` and another to handle `m_description`. How can I keep a single `Foo` object in memory and have these two `QStandardItem` objects refer to it?

In my question there's the implicit assumption that one must create a `QStandardItem` object for each (row, column) pair. Please let me know if this is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A post in qtcentre](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/67512-Hierarchical-disparate-data-structure-and-MVD-(QStandardItemModel-QTreeView)?highlight=qstandarditemodel+tree) suggested Chapter 4 of [Advanced Qt Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635906) and lo and behold, there's a discussion of a tree subsclassing `QstandardItemModel` and `QStandardIteml` where each row of the tree is made up of three `QstandardItem` handling different properties of a single object. 
The implementation source code is [freely available](https://www.qtrac.eu/aqpbook.html)

Basically, one has:

```
class myItem : public QStandardItem {
public:
  myItem(Foo &afoo) : QStandardItem(afoo.getName()), m_foo(afoo) {
    m_description = new QStandardItem(afoo.getDescription());
    }
  QstandardItem *m_description; // display m_description
private:
  Foo &m_foo;    
};
```

and then we insert a row of two QstandardItem in our model tree

```
class myModel: public QStandardItemModel {

  StandardItem *myModel::appendRow(QStandardItem *parent, Foo &afoo)
  {
      auto *doublet = new myItem(afoo);
      parent->appendRow(QList<QStandardItem*>() << doublet
              << double->m_description);
      return nameItem;  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`QStandardItemModel` is all about storing the data in the model, so each cell is represented by a `QStandardItem` which holds that cell's data.

If the data is already stored elsewhere and should not be duplicated, then the `QStandardItemModel` is the wrong approach and a custom model is the way to go.

A custom model, in the case of a tree structure derived from `QAbstractItemModel`, is just an interface between the view and the data, so the data resides only once in memory.

Comment: I had declared `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo *)` and stored a `QVariant<Foo *>` in the `QStandardItem` to avoid storing the `Foo` object. However, this still led me having to instantiate two `QStandardItem` objects for every `Foo` object, and I was hoping there was some design workaround.

Comment: As I said: the `QStandardItemModel` uses one `QStandardItem` per cell as its design principle. Its use case is to store data in the model rather than being an interface to data stored elsewhere.